# CEditBox Problem

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

VC++ 6.0, MFC application

In `CEditBox` (`IDC_EDIT1`) I have created a `CString` variable (`m_strEdit1`). How do I validate that the input is a number, including sign (+ and -)?
eg: (+10, -56)

It should not accept alphanumeric characters. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [CString::SpanIncluding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300657%28VS.60%29.aspx)?

Comment: i want to enter only numbers not characters please give me the one example thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this by validating the characters as they're entered:

---

```
class CEditBox public CEdit
{
    afx_msg void OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

---

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEditBox, CEdit)
    ON_WM_CHAR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CEditBox::OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{
    // quick validation
    if (nChar != _T('+') && nChar != _T('-') && !isdigit(nChar))
        return;

    CString strText;
    GetWindowText(strText);

    int nStartChar;
    int nEndChar;
    GetSel(nStartChar, nEndChar);

    CString strNewText = strText.Left(nStartChar) + 
                         nChar + 
                         strText.Right(strText.GetLength() - nEndChar);

    CString strFirst = strNewText.Left(1);

    // is first character valid?
    if (strFirst != _T("+") && strFirst != _T("-") && && !isdigit(strFirst[0]))
        return;

    CString strSecond = strNewText.Mid(1);

    // are remaining characters all digits? (ie no more + or -)
    for (int i = 0; i < strSecond.GetLength(); ++i)
    {
        if (!isdigit(strSecond[i]))
            return;
    }

    CEdit::OnChar(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```